# Was Captain Picard's interest in Shakespeare a result of Patrick Stewart being cast in the role?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, jean-luc-picard

Was Picard always intended to have an interest in Shakespeare, or did this come along with ([classically trained Shakespearean actor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrick_Stewart#:%7E:text=In%201966%2C%20Stewart%20became%20a%20member%20of%20the%20Royal%20Shakespeare%20Company)) Patrick Stewart?

It's a huge part of his character, but was it always the plan?

Comment: Without evidence, I'd say "probably."  Shakespeare had been in *Star Trek* since *TOS*, although moreso in the movies.  It gives the characters some cultural background the audience can relate to, and it ages better than Woodstock references.

Comment: I vote yes -- I would imagine writers get all sorts of inspiration as they try to create new episodes. Maybe even Sir Patrick suggested it.

Comment: It’s also possible that they wanted Picard to be a Shakespeare fan and that’s one reason why Stewart got the part

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Shakespeare, as well as other British influence, was initially not part of the role

Captain Julien Picard (later then renamed to Jean-Luc) was originally envisioned to be much more "french", with no hints to Shakespeare at all.
The earliest characterisation I could find describes him as a "distinguished man in his 50s"

[image: Excerpt from Starlog 118, describing Julien Picard as a distinguished man in his mid-50s]

*(Source: Starlog 118)*

"The Bible", a document that summarises all the characters for the authors, shows no hint of Shakespeare, but instead emphasises his pride of his French heritage:

[image: Characterization of Jean Luc Picard in "The Bible"]

*(Source: The Next Generation Writer's Guide)*

Besides Stewart, four actors were cast for the role of Picard, none of which have a strong Shakespearian background:

- Mitch Ryan
- Roy Thinnes
- Yaphet Kotto
- Patrick Bauchau

The latter was a favourite of Roddenberry, which is unsurprising; his Belgian background would make a convincing Frenchman. Bauchau also has no Shakespeare training.

[image: Memo around casting, mentioning Bauchau to be a favorite for the role of Picard.]

([Source](https://lettersofnote.com/2010/08/25/star-trekcasting/))

Comment: Interesting casting "what ifs" -- Yaphet Kotto as Picard and Wesley Snipes as Geordi! No Marina Sirtis?

Comment: @RobertF Sirtis auditioned for Macha Hernandez (later reworked to Tasha Yar) before Roddenberry switched her and Crosby around. Also, did you notice Rosalind Chao (Keiko O‘Brien) auditioning as Yar?

Comment: I did see that, interesting. Also Tim Russ (who played one of the Enterprise thieves in a TNG episode & Tuvok in Voyager) and Eric Menyuk (the Traveler). And Kevin Peter Hall auditioned for Geordi! Hall was over 7 feet tall & played the alien in the Predator films.